# Asking about detecting the tampered/duplicated region in one image

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

Recently, I have been doing the research about how to detect the duplicated region in an image by using OpenCV+eclipse in Ubuntu.I also read the references the code of SIFT, SURF, Feature2d+Homomorphy, but these code is just the comparison between the image object and image scene? I do not know how to merge these algorithms into an image. So that I can use it to detect the duplicated region in AN image.

Comment: with SIFT/SURF you would try to find the second best match for each feature in the same image and compare it with the best match, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the method through which you are setting your ROI. You are using `cvSetImageROI()` which is used for "IplImage" not for "Mat" images. And on the other hand, you are loading an image in Mat format. That's the reason of that error.

I have written a code. You can modify the code as per your need. The code will save the smaller images in a folder "smaller_images". So, don't forget to create a new folder with name "smaller_images".

```
int main(  )
{
    Mat image;
    int width_step;
    int height_step;
    //image = imread( argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    image = imread( "myImage.jpeg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    int rows = image.rows;
    int cols = image.cols;

    cv::Size s = image.size();
    rows = s.height;
    cols = s.width;
    cout<<"The width of the image: "<<cols<< endl;
    cout<<"The height of the image: "<<rows<< endl;

    cout<< "Input your width_step= ";
    cin>>width_step;
    cout<< "Input your height_step= ";
    cin>>height_step;
    double each_width= cols/width_step;
    double each_height= rows/height_step;
    cout<< "The width_size of each region "<<each_width<< endl;
    cout<< "The height_size of each region "<<each_height<< endl;
       //-------------------------  

    int i=0;

    for(int x=0; x<(cols - width_step); x++ )
    {       
        for (int y=0; y < (rows - height_step ); y++)
        {
            if( x <(cols - width_step) &&  y < (rows - height_step ) )
                {
                Mat smallerImage;

                smallerImage.create(height_step, width_step, CV_8UC3);
                Rect regionOfInterest = Rect (x, y, width_step, height_step); // Rect (min_x,min_y, cols, rows);
                //mySquare= original_frame(regionOfInterest);
                smallerImage = image( regionOfInterest );



                ///Increasing the value of "x" and "y" for next image for "Rect()"
                x = x + width_step;
                y = y + height_step;
                i = i+1;



                /// Saving the smaller image to a folder called "smaller_image"
                char name_writeImage[255];
                sprintf(name_writeImage, "smaller_images/%d.jpg" ,i );      
                imwrite(name_writeImage,smallerImage );
            }
        }   
    }       


    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help very much . The code is very useful for me, I will use it to detect some similar key features of each sub-image by using SIFT algorithm in one big image. It is the first time when I am familiar with openCV. I love it, I will try to finish it.

Comment: please upvote my other answers for this question as i have not received points for other answers.

Comment: After doing an demo,the code do not divide an big image into many subimages with their pixel are adjacent. Are there any problem related to the iterator? Because when I arrange all of subimages together. It is not the original image.

Comment: ok, I see. But I have a problem with upvote because the score of reputation I get is not enough - it must be above 15 reputation. To be honest, when I get enough, I will upvote later with all your help^_^.

Comment: ahh no problem...actually it will be helpful for others too to know that the other answers are also correct/helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your application exactly but you can define some small region of interests in your image...you can also create independent images from those regions and then through a recursive loop you can check some much is the similarity between different regions.

**For example:** You can have a look at the following illustration where we have a bigger image and then we define few region of interests (ROI) and then we create smaller images from those ROI and then we can find similarity between those smaller images (which are actually a part of the original image)
[image: See the image]

Comment: okay, I know your answer, but I have a question about how to divide an image into n-part of ROI and the size of each ROI. I think your above map is not flexible with any size of one input image.Please help me about this problem.

Comment: i have explained it in separate answer...have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

you can decide yourself in how many smaller images you would like to divide your image. So, lets say that you want to create 4 smaller images from your given image whose size is 400 x 400. So, your each image will be of size 100 x 100.

Ok, now you have to create 4 images.

**First image:** Top left corner (0,0), width= 400/4 = 100, height = 400/4 =100

```
            Mat image1;
            image1.create(height, width, CV_8UC3);
            Rect regionOfInterest_1 = Rect (0,0, width, height);
            image1= original_Image(regionOfInterest_1);
```

**Second image:** Top left corner (0,101), width= 400/4 = 100, height = 400/4 =100

```
            Mat image2;
            image2.create(height, width, CV_8UC3);
            Rect regionOfInterest_2 = Rect (0,101, width, height);
            image2= original_Image(regionOfInterest_2);
```

**Third image:** Top left corner (0,101), width= 400/4 = 100, height = 400/4 =100

```
            Mat image3;
            image3.create(height, width, CV_8UC3);
            Rect regionOfInterest_3 = Rect (101,0, width, height);
            image3= original_Image(regionOfInterest_3);
```

and so on...you can do it using a for loop instead of writing it separately. But first you need to understand the concept of creating a smaller image from the original image using "Rect Region of interest".

One tip: Have a look at the arguments of `Rect(x , y, width , height)`. In openCV, X-coordinate represents the columns/width and Y-coordinate represents the rows/height.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it and if I have any further related question. I will ask you. May I have your email? Because I am a newbie on this field, and it is the project of mine. I think that I need to study more about this one.

Comment: when you create an image in opencv...you must tell some details about it...8 represents 8 bit image, U- unsigned char, C3- three channels (e.g. RGB)...try to explore yourself as much as possible..openCV documentation is quite nice. You can easily find any function from here <http://docs.opencv.org/genindex.html>

Comment: This is my code about read each interest of region(ROI) in one image, but when I build it, it has an error
"../src/ROI.cpp:56:33: error: cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘IplImage* {aka _IplImage*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void cvSetImageROI(IplImage*, CvRect)’ make: * [src/ROI.o] Error 1 "